# Cant read values from Workspace in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a variable in the Workspace uavMission.origin which can't be read in the simulink model

I use the from Workspace Block
[image: From Workspace]

I get the error that the origin does not exist
[image: Error Message]

But uavMission has orgin
[image: Variable]

I tried reloading the workspace, but this did not help.
Is there another way for reading values from the workspace?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was, that a uavMission object existed in the model without a origin object. When creating a object named uavMission2 it worked.

Also I am using the constant block, because based on the documentation of matlab the from workspace block is used for time series